# Multibinding combobox with Buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I am new to WPF and I have following problem:

in my app I have 4x4 grid that is filled with buttons, and combobox next to it.
In combobox I am storing colors, now what I'd like to do is that after clicking button it changes color to color that is selected in combobox, and after clicking this button again color changes back to default button background color, also after changing selecteditem in combobox I would like all buttons that already have color different than default button background color to change color to the one selected from combobox. How can I achieve it?

Here is image of how it should look like(Define Shapes window):[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfZez.jpg)

Here is what I have so far:

```
 public partial class DefineShapes : Window
{
    public DefineShapes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Shape1Color.ItemsSource = typeof(Colors).GetProperties();
        Shape1Color.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
        Shape1Color.SelectedValue = "{Binding SelectedId}";
        Shape1Color.SelectedIndex = 2;

    }


    private void Shape1Color_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Color selectedColor = (Color)(Shape1Color.SelectedItem as PropertyInfo).GetValue(null, null);
    }
}
```

Shape1Color is said ComboBox.

Here is my **Grid containing buttons**:

```
<Grid Name="Shape1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ShowGridLines="true">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></Button>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1"></Button>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="2"></Button>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="3"></Button>

            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1"></Button>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></Button>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"></Button>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"></Button>

            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2"></Button>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"></Button>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"></Button>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"></Button>

            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="3"></Button>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"></Button>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"></Button>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3"></Button>
        </Grid>
```

Here is my **ComboBox**:

```
<ComboBox Name="Shape1Color" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="20" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
               SelectionChanged="Shape1Color_SelectionChanged"   VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want a quick and dirty solution, you could store the 'old' color in the Tag-Property of each button, roughly like this:

```
private void Shape1Color_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var senderButton = sender as Button;
    if (senderButton.Tag is Color) {
       senderButton.Background = (Color)senderButton.Tag; // maybe make SolidColorBrush from color instead, here
       senderButton.Tag = null;
    } else {
      Color selectedColor = (Color)(Shape1Color.SelectedItem as PropertyInfo).GetValue(null, null);
      senderButton.Tag = selectedColor;
    }
}
```